# How can I make use of the json string my Java code provides PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have no experience with PHP, yesterday was my first day working with it. My Java code makes an HTTP request in whose body there is a JSON formatted String. It looks like this:

```
{
   "Services":[
      {
         "description":"Testing",
         "quantity":12.25
      },
      {
         "description":"More tests.",
         "quantity":1.3
      },
      {
         "description":"Writing this thread.",
         "quantity":0.5
      }
   ]
}
```

In Java this was JSONObjects put into a JSONArray which then was put into a JSONObject again.

What I want to do with this is put every `{ "description":"xxxx", "quantity":xxxx }` into a MySQL table, each with it's own row of course. I have very little experience with MySQL too, I would be very happy if you could assist me with my needs.

My method of interacting with the MySQL database is using PDO. Please don't hesitate to ask if you need some more info.

**EDIT:** 
Now this is what I get from the code sample below. I think I'm using it wrong.

```
<?php

$string = '{"Services":[{"description":"Testing","quantity":12.25},{"description":"More tests.","quantity":1.3},{"description":"Writing this thread.","quantity":0.5}]}';

$json = json_decode($string, true);
$query = "INSERT INTO services VALUES "; 
foreach ($json AS $key => $value){
    $query += "( "+$value; //no idea where I have to close this bracket..
}
echo($query);

?>
```

What I need is to get into every inner array and then add the two values inside the inner array to the `$query`, so it looks like `INSERT INTO services VALUES ("Testing", 12.25), ("More tests.", 1.3), ("Writing this thread.", 0.5)`. This is the output of var_dump($json):

```
array(1) { ["Services"]=> array(3) 
{ [0]=> array(2) { ["description"]=> string(7) "Testing" ["quantity"]=> float(12.25) } 
  [1]=> array(2) { ["description"]=> string(11) "More tests." ["quantity"]=> float(1.3) }
  [2]=> array(2) { ["description"]=> string(20) "Writing this thread." ["quantity"]=> float(0.5) } 
} 
}
```

Comment: `json_decode($json_string)` Will convert it to a PHP Array

Comment: `var_dump(json_decode($json_string, true))` like in the tutorials gives me no output to the page. Is this now an array which contains arrays (like it would make sense)? If yes, how do I access the values?

Comment: Did you actually assign `$json_string` the POSTED json before doing the decode?

Comment: Well, just to try how this would look I copied my example and pasted it beside the variable declaration. So, technically yes.

Comment: Can you edit your post with your sample PHP code

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot the semicolon. Damn this semicolon :) I edited what I get from the output.

Comment: See my (very basic) example in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below will assign a PHP array called `$my_array` from your json. It then loops through that array, assigning $key and $value through each loop. I believe Arrays and looping through them are very similar concepts in every language. So if you know Java this should make sense to you.

```
$my_array = json_decode($json_string, true);

foreach ($my_array AS $key => $n_array) {
    foreach ($n_array AS $key_n => $data) {

        $description = $data['description'];
        $quantity = $data['quantity'];

        mysqli_query("INSERT INTO services VALUES ('$description', '$quantity' )");


    }

}
```

The above is a very simple example of how to get the correct variables out. You should be using prepared statements to actually do the insert and just use the loop to get the data you need.

Comment: I tried building a query with this, but I am getting no results. I edited my post, maybe you could look at it again.